# How to get records where associated's associated_id is a given value

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a suburbs activerecord that belongs to a city and have many listings, I want to get the listings where the suburb city is a given value.

```
    listings = Listing.joins(:suburbs).where('listings.updated_at >= ?', 2.months.ago).where('city_id = ?', city_id)
```

Comment: I have updated the answer with more info. Do check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you have these associations defined. Correct me if I am wrong.

In Suburb class:

```
has_many :listings
belongs_to :city
```

In Listing class:

```
belongs_to :suburb
```

In City class:

```
has_many :suburbs
```

Now to fetch all the listings where city is `city_id`, you need to join listings with suburb and then with city and then you need to filter out the results. Go through this [link](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins) to understand better

```
listings = Listing.joins(suburb: :city).where('listings.updated_at >= ?', 2.months.ago).where(cities: {id: city_id })
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find a suburb by given id
2. Find all related listings for the suburb. Check [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-many-collection) for more info.

```rb
Suburb.find(city_id).listings.where('updated_at >= ?', 2.months.ago)
```

Comment: I want the listings for all the suburbs in that city, this will only return one suburb. But I will go through the docs thanks.

Comment: There are few issues with this. First, a city might have many suburbs. Second, `find(city_id)` will look for suburbs with id: city_id which is wrong. It should have been `find_by(city_id: city_id)` instead.